# How can I edit Strings with unknown delimiters

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have to write a converter for cnc machine code.

I have no experience with Regex and its hard to follow others examples, especially regarding the creating of the "Delimiter"-Expressions.

I am struggling with deleting the String partially (from the Character "Z" until the end of the line). Basically this is what I got and needs to be converted:

```
N11 G0 X49.000 Y30.329 Z0.000
N12 G0 X49.000 Y30.329 Z-1.000
N13 G1 X49.000 Y50.329 Z-1.000 F500
N14 X49.000 Y150.000 Z0.000
N15 X49.300 Y150.700 Z-15.000 F400
N16 X50.000 Y151.000 Z+1000.000
N17 X150.000 Y151.000 Z-1.000
```

Result should be:

```
N11 G0 X49.000 Y30.329 A49.000 B30.329
N12 G0 X49.000 Y30.329 A49.000 B30.329
N13 G1 X49.000 Y50.329 A49.000 B50.329 F500
N14 X49.000 Y150.000 A49.000 B150.000
N15 X49.300 Y150.700 A49.300 B150.700 F400
N16 X50.000 Y151.000 A50.000 B151.000
N17 X150.000 Y151.000 A150.000 B151.000
```

This is the iteration where I want to edit those Strings:

```
for (int i = 11; i < oldIso.Length; i++)
{
    converted.AppendLine(RemoveBetween(oldIso[i], 'z', endofline));
}
```

So I am not sure how I could solve this as good as possible. I thought about deleting from the character "Z" until the end of the Line. I will care about the "F500 / F400" - lines later then. 
The A and Bs are exactly the same like the X and Ys Values just with a different Character .

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Where are the `A49`'s and `B30`'s coming from?

Comment: The A and Bs are exactly the same like the X and Ys Values just with a different Character .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do this - assuming the format you've posted above is reliable and consistent - is to split the string into an array of space-delimited strings. Iterate through and reconcatenate the string while skipping any element whose first character is 'Z'.

This could look something like so:

```
string line = "N12 G0 X49.000 Y30.329 Z-1.000";
string[] splitLine = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string splitString in splitLine)
{
    if (splitString[0] != 'Z')
    {
        // don't forget to add the spaces back
        stringBuilder.Append(splitString + " ");
    }
}

string finalString = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

This could be off-base - you've said that the delimiters are unknown, but every line you posted as a sample is predictably delimited. This example will work with anything you want to remove, though - if you decide you don't want tokens beginning with F, just add that conditional to the original, like so:

```
if (splitString[0] != 'Z' && splitString[0] != 'F' /* and etc. and etc. */)
```

The A and B segments we'd need a little more information about, and seems partially like a separate question. For starters, we'd need to know whether it matters that the lines are formatted in the order you've shown (X Y A B) or whether those tokens can exist at any point in the string.

Comment: Thanks for this good idea ! I am going to try this and will mark it as correct when I got it running :).

Answer (score 1):

this regex will give you your new line for each line of input, using capturing groups :

```
string line = "N11 G0 X49.000 Y30.329 Z0.000";
var newLine = Regex.Replace(line, @"([^X]+)X([^Y]+)Y([^Z]+).+", @"$1X$2Y$3A$2B$3");

//newLine = N11 G0 X49.000 Y30.329 A49.000 B30.329
```

Comment: Wow this is crazy, but I can't understand how this works. Thanks to you as well!

Comment: You should look into capture groups, pretty much what's in parenthesis is captured and reproduced in the replace